# iOS development and client control-- What are my legal and best options?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, licensing

I work for a company that would like to create an app that we can distribute to our customers.  We manufacture industrial equipment and we would like to provide an iPhone/iPad app to our customers that can interact with their equipment.

The problem is that we would prefer that the app not be downloaded from the App Store.  We would like for this application to be available for our customers free-of-charge and would also like for them to have the ability to download and install the application on as many devices as they desire.  However, we do not want non-customers (ahem, competitors) to be able to download and use our application.

What options are available?  We have considered allowing the app to be available through the app store but in that case the app would be locked until the user entered an application key.  This would keep the app free to download and it would give us the ability to control who could use our software.  I'm not sure, however, if that is allowable by the  Apple TOS.

The Enterprise license sounds like a potential option. If  it is, what are the specific steps necessary for installing an iOS app on an Apple device if not through the App Store?  I'm also not sure if it would break the TOS to distribute our app for this purpose under the Enterprise license.  Is that the case?

What options do I have?  Please realize, I don't own a Mac and I've never even attempted to write or distribute an iOS application-- I'm 100% new to all of this.  Thanks for you help.

**EDIT**

Thank you all for the wonderful responses that I have so far received.  Half of the questions that I have stem from the fact that I can't find the actual TOS agreement that I would have to sign if I became a standard or enterprise developer.  ([Yes](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=4&gs_id=dd&xhr=t&q=iphone+developer+tos&qe=aXBobyBkZXZlbG9wZXIgdG9z&qesig=KiRNKqgwLANeYbv0no1lHA&pkc=AFgZ2tlWffapVLOrSjgvnSjWU6fFXxUDrmQSgvx8E6q8SywlXhLay4gWaPFIS1jDCj50KsEn7wHDfP1uHKyP9OBWZ2BNpnEN9Q&pq=ios%20developer%20tos&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=ipho+developer+tos&aq=0jl&aqi=g-jl2&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=2218936981cdb3ba&biw=1680&bih=965), [I've](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=ios+developer+tos&pbx=1&oq=ios+developer+tos&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=61153l61511l8l62192l3l3l1l0l0l1l193l283l1.1l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=2218936981cdb3ba&biw=1680&bih=965) [googled](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=6&gs_id=ey&xhr=t&q=apple+developer+tos&qe=YXBwbGUgZGV2ZWxvcGVyIHRvcw&qesig=XnX3cQ7i0jvkV-6jgYTaOQ&pkc=AFgZ2tlWffapVLOrSjgvnSjWU6fFXxUDrmQSgvx8E6q8SywlXhLay4gWaPFIS1jDCj50KsEn7wHDfP1uHKyP9OBWZ2BNpnEN9Q&pq=ios%20developer%20tos&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=apple+developer+tos&aq=0&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=2218936981cdb3ba&biw=1680&bih=965) [it](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=apple+enterprise+developer+tos&pbx=1&oq=apple+enterprise+developer+tos&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=30292l32083l10l33043l11l9l0l0l0l6l275l1966l1.1.7l9l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=2218936981cdb3ba&biw=1680&bih=965).)  Does anyone have a link to such documents?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to distribute your app outside the App Store, you need to get an [iOS Developer Entreprise license](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) ($299/year). You're going to need a Dun & Bradstreet (D-U-N-S) number to enroll and can only deploy to 500 (registered) devices.

**Edit**: Another option would be to demand the user some authentication (such as user/pass) to use the app (think Facebook or Twitter). You could provide your clients with the credentials to ensure only a certain users have access to the app.

Comment: What if you want to distribute to more than 500 devices?  How about 100,000?

Comment: Your second option was my initial idea but for the sake of simplicity I am hoping for a better option.  Logging in is a step we would like to avoid because a customer (company) may have many users who would can use our application.  Preferably, if we can't distribute the app directly to them, we would like to be able to give them a customer key which each user must enter the first time the run the application.  I could easily code this, however, I don't know if such an app would pass the Apple App Verification process.

Comment: It's the customer, not him who should enroll in the program. See my answer below.

Comment: Apple has a history of rejecting apps that are intended for a limited audience. Since you asked about deploying to 100k devices, I'm guessing you could contact the review team and explain your situation in case it was rejected.

Answer (score 2):

I think @ibeitia's answer is the best one, but here's an additional option: put the app on the app store, but make it all-but-useless without a login to your server.

For example, the Google+ app is useless unless you have a Google account.

You'd have to give a login to Apple so they can vet it, and of course I can't *guarantee* they'll allow it, but it's an option I'd consider.

(If you do go down that route, send an email to Apple's approval team asking for clarification before you start development!)

Comment: Ah, looks like ibeitia been coming up with that idea at the same time. :-)

Comment: ...And how does one contact the Apple approval team before purchasing a licensing agreement?  (Once again, I have tried to google it.)

Comment: One of these should do it: http://developer.apple.com/contact/ If they can't help you, I'd consider paying $99 for the basic license and put it on the research budget. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

> I work for a company that would like to create an app that we can
>   distribute to our customers.

From http://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html (bold is mine)

> I am a developer who wants to create an in house app for my client.
>   Can I join the iOS Developer Enterprise Program to do that?
>
> The iOS Developer Enterprise Program should be used to **develop and
>   distribute proprietary in-house applications to your own employees
>   within your own company**. As such, your company would not qualify for
>   direct Program enrollment in this situation. We would suggest that
>   your client apply for enrollment in the Program, and, once enrolled in
>   the Program, your client may add the appropriate developers from your
>   company to their iOS Development Team.

The Enterprise Developer program doesn't allow you to sell your app to your customers. It's the customer, not you, who should enroll in the program.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet will be to use Apple's B 2 B program:

http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/

This will allow you to have apps in Apple's business app store (not the ordinary app store), and control who gets the apps. You'd provide the redemption codes to your customers.

btw, I can confirm that providing an app with a login to make it useful would be okay with Apple - I've done it before.

Answer (score 0):

Well your options are really limited.
You could go with the enterprise license but this is still limited to 500 device which still need to be register with the some how. (never had to work with the enterprise license).

But could you not make your app available in the appstore foor free but only make it work with you equipment. Thus make the app search for the equipment (via bonjour of wifi) and only work when it finds the device. This will make getting the accepted a bit harder but will work. There are some IP camera manager that work that way.

If your competitors really want your app they will get it one way or an other.
Just be sure you release an app before the competitors, do that way your company has the advantage.

Comment: He's given you his reason for not putting the app in the App Store: "we do not want...competitors...to be able to download and use our application".

Comment: This might be the solution we have to go with, but the problem is that much of our equipment is available in a public place and under certain circumstances, competitors may even have access to our customer networks.  Searching for the hardware would be something that they would be able to do if they had our app on their iPhones. :(